# Testar se método remove item uma lista (Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, array, jasmine

Tenho um método em um serviço que remove itens com mais de 60 dias de uma lista.

```
self.removerAntigas = function () {
        var dataCorte = new Date();
        var dataAux = dataCorte.getDate();
        dataCorte.setDate(dataAux - 60);
        itens.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.data <= dataCorte) {
                itens.splice (itens.indexOf(item),1);
            }
        });
    };
```

Também tenho o método que obtem todos os itens dessa lista:

```
self.obterTodos = function (){
    return itens;
}
```

E o método adicionar:

```
self.adicionar = function () {
    var item = {
        data: new Date(),
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        conectado: true,
        sincronizado: false
    };
    itens.push(item);
};
```

Como posso escrever um teste, utilizando Jasmine, que me diga se removi os itens corretos dessa lista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta algum código na pergunta, não está claro de onde vêm o `itens`. Mas vou dar um exemplo com `this` em vêz de `itens` que pelo que leio do código acho que é isso que queres.

```
describe('removerAntigas', function () {

    it("should add new item", function () {
        window.itens = [gerador(), gerador(), gerador()];
        window.adicionar()
        expect(window.itens.length).toEqual(4);
    });
    it("should return all items", function () {
        expect(window.obterTodos()).toEqual(window.itens);
    });
    it("should return all items", function () {
        expect(window.itens.length == 4).toBeTruthy();
        window.removerAntigas();
        expect(window.itens.length < 4).not.toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/osfwh0rh/

Comment: Mas nesse caso, eu preciso chamar o adicionar criando uma lista fake.
Com datas que precisaria remover e datas que não precisa. 
O meu adicionar já cria o objeto "data" com new Date(), e nesse caso quero passar as datas para ele criar a lista. 
Essa lista vem do serviço, ela é manipulada diretamente lá e não contem itens.

Comment: @JulianaPrado num teste tens sempre de ter alguma lista. Como não deste um exemplo criei uma fake. Se tens um exemplo melhor. Coloca aqui que eu integro ou adapta a utilização do código que dei...